# UISplitViewController Pushing Detail View onto Table/Master View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having this issue where in landscape mode on an iPhone 7 Plus when clicking on a cell in the table view on the left side of the device the content gets displayed on top of the table view, or replacing the table view. A split view controller should display the content on the right side in this case. The old content still seems to display on the right side as well.

In portrait mode everything seems to be working fine.

Not sure what code or details to post as it's a really strange problem and not quite sure where the problem exactly is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug on Apple side. I solved it as follows.

1. Control-click on your Storyboard and open as source code.
2. Locate your segue from master to detail view
3. Add the following parameter 'action="showDetailViewController:sender:"' before 'id="..."'

Comment: Thank you! I was tearing my hair out for nearly an hour and this turned out to be the solution!